Using WordPress post meta functions with array variables on WooCommerce orders
I see in many places that WordPress will automatically serialize arrays with update_post_meta.
But, their docs state that you should serialize it before using update_post_meta. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_post_meta/
I am also getting different results when using get_post_meta that uses a serialized value or the array.
    $val = array();
    $val['one'] = 1;
    $val['two'] = 2;
    $val['threed']['x'] = 'ex';
    $val['threed']['y'] = 'why';

    $ser = serialize($val);

    update_post_meta($order_id, 'testing arr', $val);
    update_post_meta($order_id, 'testing ser arr', $ser);

    // This was saved in the table as...
    // a:3:{s:3:"one";i:1;s:3:"two";i:2;s:6:"threed";a:2:{s:1:"x";s:2:"ex";s:1:"y";s:3:"why";}}
    // s:88:"a:3:{s:3:"one";i:1;s:3:"two";i:2;s:6:"threed";a:2:{s:1:"x";s:2:"ex";s:1:"y";s:3:"why";}}";

    $testarr = get_post_meta($order_id, 'testing arr');
    $testarrser = get_post_meta($order_id, 'testing ser arr');

Using get_post_meta for each of the above and printing the array gives the following: 
NOTE 1: get_post_meta($id, $field, true) and get_post_meta($id, $field, false) return the same data structure.
NOTE 2: These were not unserialized - just print_r() the returned values.

testarr: Array(
    [0] => Array (
            [one] => 1
            [two] => 2
            [threed] => Array (
                    [x] => ex
                    [y] => why
                )
        )
)

testarrser: Array(
    [0] => a:3:{s:3:"one";i:1;s:3:"two";i:2;s:6:"threed";a:2:{s:1:"x";s:2:"ex";s:1:"y";s:3:"why";}}
)

Please explain the correct way to update_post_meta to retrieve the expected array.


No, you don't need to serialize an array before using WordPress add_post_meta() or update_post_meta() functions, as those functions will do that internally using included maybe_serialize() function.
Now when using get_post_meta() set the 3rd parameter to true to get the correct initial saved array, like
$testarr = get_post_meta($order_id, 'testing arr', true);

Caution, for WooCommerce Orders (and HPOS compatibility):
You should not use anymore WordPress post meta functions, instead you should use CRUD methods from the WC_Order object like:
$data = array();
$data['one'] = 1;
$data['two'] = 2;
$data['threed']['x'] = 'ex';
$data['threed']['y'] = 'why';

$order = wc_get_order( $order_id ); // Get the WC_Order Object (if needed)

$order->update_meta_data( 'testing_arr', $data ); // Add the metadata
$order->save(); // Save it to the database

To get this array from the WC_Order object use:
$order = wc_get_order( $order_id ); // Get the WC_Order Object (if needed)

$data = $order->get_meta('testing_arr'); // Get the metadata

This way is compatible with High Performance Orders Storage (HPOS) as WooCommerce is now using custom tables in the database.
Related:

How to get WooCommerce order details
Filtering orders list in WooCommerce with HPOS


Thank you LoicTheAztec! I love explicit answers!! (I wonder why WP said to serialize it first. But I will take your advice :))

Also, Yes, this is for order data and we're condensing several lines of related data into one table row. Thank for extending your explanation for the HPOS.

Okay! Just wanted to give you a kudos! Oops! Maybe I shouldn't reply even that. Heck! You deserve a :).
